# DjangoRest Serializer returns empty object

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

When I try to serialize some object I get empty object. 
Product.objects have object

model.py

```
class Product (models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
   price = models.IntegerField()
   count_of_flowers = models.IntegerField()
   type = models.ForeignKey('Type')
   box_type = models.ForeignKey('Box', blank=True)
   flowers_color = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

class Type(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

class Box(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

Serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Product, Type, Box

class BoxSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Box
        field = ('name')

class TypeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Type
        field = ('name')


class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   boxes = BoxSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
   types = TypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)   
   class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = ('id','name','price','count_of_flowers','boxes','types''flowers_color')
```

And then, when I use view or in shell Serializer return empty object.
Also I tried to del dependency between Box and Type and deleted the same 'fields'.

Comment: what precisely you did in the shell and what you got?

Comment: Looking at your model, one `product` will have only one `box` and one `type`. Why have you used a serializer with `many=True`.

Comment: I just tried, it still not work to add data from box and type

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Need to use `serializers.ModelSerializer`...

It needs to look like:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
...
```